# Latter treed $\longrightarrow$ letter trade

Tags: letters

In a twist on consonant sameness, each clue leads to a pair of words that swap their vowels to reveal a common phrase.

### Example

The clue

> Latest, forested (6, 5)

has solution

> latter, treed $\longrightarrow$ letter trade

because

> latter, treed = lttr + ae, trd + ee
>   $\qquad\qquad$and
>   letter, trade = lttr + ee, trd + ae.

Note that the sequences of consonants and vowels each maintain their order but may be combined in a different way. The numbers in parentheses indicate the number of letters in each clued word (*latter*, *treed*); unlike in this example, the words in the answer phrase (*letter*, *trade*) may have different numbers of letters, if the number of vowels in each word differs.

### Clues

> 1. Annoy, squad (4, 4)
> 2. Cheers, journey (6, 4)
> 3. Drum, ambiences (5, 5)
> 4. Mushrooms, woman (5, 3)
> 5. Overacts, reduced (4, 3)
> 6. Skin, active (4, 4)
> 7. Sugary, listens (3, 5)
> 8. Thug, rind (4, 4)
> 9. Yearn, disadvantage (4, 3)

**Clarification**: In this puzzle, the vowels are only the standard *a*, *e*, *i*, *o*, and *u*; every other letter is considered a consonant.

Comment: So the clues are only used to find half of the solution, then the complete solution is "dealer's choice"?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'm not sure what this refers to. Is it the fact that there are multiple ways the consonants and vowels can recombine in each word?

Comment: It just feels like a partial puzzle. The clues and letter counts offer a path to the left-hand words, but there's no motivation for any of the right-hand words aside from "these words work, I guess". I understand the hesitation in making the clues also descriptive of the RHS, but without something pointing at a "right answer", it just feels unsatisfying.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Ah, I see. I agree, and while planning I had clues for the final answers as well but then worried about backsolving eliminating the need for the vowel swap gimmick. Then I considered writing vague tangential clues for the RHS that would only make sense in the context of the answer, but that was also a little unsatisfactory because it just felt like poor cluing. Definitely something to think about in the future. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @IanMacDonald I disagree. The right hand side is what **makes** it a complete puzzle. Yes, as we saw, what qualifies as a "common phrase" is a bit subjective. But I think noedne did a great job of picking words where, when you get the answer, you get that satisfying feeling of knowing that you got it correct. That's how I felt for each one I completed anyway, and when I saw the answers that others found. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @ferret The RHS is certainly a requirement for it to be puzzling, but there's nothing in the clue that motivates it. If a clue ended up with a word pair that had multiple possible RHS, there'd be no way to choose a correct one.

Comment: @IanMacDonald sure, "if." But there aren't any with multiple possible answers. The only questionable one in my opinion is "fly spray." But overall it's a well-done puzzle with only 1 good answer for each pair of words. It's not any more subjective than a LOT of puzzles on here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#9 I think is a trick question, which is appropriate since it was the last one.

> 1. Annoy, squad $\implies$ rile, team $\implies$ **real time**
>  2. Cheers, journey $\implies$ elates, tour $\implies$ **lotus-eater** ([solved by ManyPinkHats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66155/15629))
>  3. Drum, ambiences $\implies$ tabla, auras $\implies$ **tabula rasa**
>  4. Mushrooms, woman $\implies$ fungi, she $\implies$ **feng shui**
>  5. Overacts, reduced $\implies$ hams, low $\implies$ **Ohm’s law**
>  6. Skin, active $\implies$ flay, spry $\implies$ **fly spray** ([solved by hagfy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66056/15629))
>  7. Sugary, listens $\implies$ -ose (suffix), hears $\implies$ **sea horse**
>  8. Thug, rind $\implies$ goon, peel $\implies$ **gene pool**
>  9. Yearn, disadvantage $\implies$ long, con $\implies$ **long con**

Comment: Great job so far, just a couple more!

Comment: @noedne pretty stumped on the last 2 :(

Comment: @noedne added a guess for #7

Comment: An interesting try for *#6*, albeit with an obscure answer phrase. As I should have clarified in the question, I am considering all letters other than the standard $5$ vowels as consonants, regardless of usage in specific words. Your interpretation was also reasonable given that *y* is used as a vowel in these two words. I appreciate the continued effort on this puzzle! I am usually reluctant to add hints, but perhaps it is time to add one.

Comment: I bet that journey translates to “rot13>gevc” in puzzle two, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ManyPinkHats, I have now proven twice in this answer that I’m unable to count

Answer (score 7):

A guess for #2: Cheers, journey (6, 4)

> ELATES, TOUR $\implies$ [lotus-eater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus-eaters)

Comment: Argh, I never came up with your first word.  I think you got it...nice work!

Comment: I came up with both of those words separately, but never together :'(

Comment: You got the last one! All of you deserve +1 for getting some really tricky answers, and @ferret will get the tick for solving the majority of the clues, probably after editing in the two other contributions for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 6):

6) Skin, active (4, 4):

> Flay, Spry $\implies$ Fly Spray

Still stuck on #2, but I really want to know what it is, so here are a couple ideas I've come up with:

> WHOOPs, Trip $\implies$ Whips Troop (some kind of soldier who uses whips?)
> Proost, Ride $\implies$ Priest Rood (barrier in a church that blocks the priest from view?)

Comment: Correct! I was under the impression that this was a common phrase, but I could very well have been mistaken. Apologies for the artificial difficulty if that was the case!

Comment: Oh wow, cool!  It very well could be a common phrase, but I just don't hang out in the right circles.  =D   I really just wasn't sure if it fit what you were looking for.  Now let's get #2 answered!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got #2

> Thanks, trip -> Thinks, trap

Comment: Good try, but the answer should be a common phrase :)

Comment: Oh, I see now. Missed that part.

Comment: No worries, the example was probably slightly misleading as "letter trade" is not a common phrase, but I wanted something thematic.